# python condition that checks if attriibute is not none errors that it is none

Tags: python, django, getattr

I have the following condition that checks to see if an object has populated value for the id attribute:

```
 if getattr(instance, 'id', True):
        
        asdf = instance.id
```

This should filter any instances that do not have an ID.  However I get the error:

> ```
> 'Session' object has no attribute 'id'
> on line: asdf = instance.id
> ```

How can the None instance.id line ever be reached?

Comment: Wel you set as default value `True`, hence it will also "fire" if the attribute does *not* exists. You can use `if hasattr(instance, 'id')` instead, of `getattr(instance, 'id', False)`

Comment: Did you mean to use hasattr() instead of getattr ()

Comment: It seems like maybe you just want: `asdf = getattr(instance, 'id', True)`. Then `asdf` will either be the `id` or `True`.

Comment: @Ahmet I believe hasattr would return true if id is = None but if the attribute existed on the object, therefor getattr is the better choice.

Comment: Does better to ask for forgiveness than permission apply here?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

> #### getattr(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named
> attribute of object. name must be a string. If the  string is the name
> of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that
> attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to
> x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned
> if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

In yout case, `default` is set to `true`, so even if `instance` doesn't have `id` attribute your function returns `true`.

I suggest you change it to `False`:

```
 if getattr(instance, 'id', False):
        asdf = instance.id
```

or (better):

```
 if hasattr(instance, 'id'):
        asdf = instance.id
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do this instead of using `hasattr()`?  What happen to the value of `asdf`  if `instance.id == 0`?

Comment: You're right. we have to assume that `instance.id` is never `0`